# Direct Protocol 4.00 - ThreeDSRequestorPriorAuthenticationInfo.threeDSReqPriorRef - how do I populate this?

Tags: opayo, 3d-secure

I'm wondering how to populate a field.

The section "A1.2 ThreeDSRequestorPriorAuthenticationInfoXML" of the Direct integration specification states

> The 3DS Requestor Prior Transaction Authentication Information contains optional information about a 3DS cardholder authentication that occurred prior to the current transaction.

The field `threeDSReqPriorRef` has the description:

> This data element provides additional information to the ACS to determine the best approach for handling a request. It will contain an ACS Transaction ID for a prior authenticated transaction (for example, the first recurring transaction that was authenticated with the cardholder).
>   This ID will be available in future via My Sage Pay and the Reporting and Admin API.

Clearly providing a prior reference will be "better", but I'm wondering how to populate it?

So I'm looking at the contents of the CReq:

```
{
  "messageType" : "CReq",
  "messageVersion" : "2.1.0",
  "threeDSServerTransID" : "0868ead0-8e3e-4c29-be1a-9689500b52fe",
  "acsTransID" : "44d368d3-31c5-472d-a27e-ad2fd2a75cc7",
  "challengeWindowSize" : "05"
```

I *assume* the required data is obtained from `acsTransID`, which I'll presumably have to store for the next use? But I'm swithering as to whether I should be cracking open the CRreq at all as this seems like an almighty smell? (also note that the above from the SagePay test system isn't valid JSON either)

Surely SagePay should be giving this reference in the response? (I don't really want to use the Reporting API to get the reference TBH ... it's a bit of a rats nest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you're going to need to bust the acsTransID out of the broken JSON response and use that. This is a best guess though. It doesn't sound as if SagePay currently return this in any form.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that I shouldn't do this though. What if the behaviour (or contents of the CReq) is different in the live system? I'd have to parse the JSON, and if it doesn't parse, append a trailing curly bracket and try again. Then I've got the issue of the field being not present etc etc. I guess if this all fails, I'd default to not storing anything.

Comment: Yeah, it's not great. It is an optional value, so I guess you could just leave it out till it's better supported.

Comment: I've just realised another flaw with breaking the ACS Transaction ID from the CReq ... most payments won't even have a CReq as they are "frictionless". So I'm a bit stumped on this one TBH. 

I've currently got something in place to break apart the CReq for the data that's got extensive unit tests and if it doesn't work it won't fail the transaction. Annoying this is a half baked SagePay solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the details of how to redirect 3DAuth, card holder name as "Challenge" but still there is no complete solution for 3D values to be sent to bank.

[Sagepay - Payment Authorised despite 3dSecure Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392637/sagepay-payment-authorised-despite-3dsecure-failure)